# Calculating cost of meal with taxes

Tags: python

Apologies, at times i struggle with basics of python.  The below code is not working.

```
def cost(c,r,t)
total cost = c*(1+r)*(1+t)
print total cost

cost(44.5, 6.75%, 15%)
```

I'm trying to find the computed total cost of meal based on the following:

```
Cost of meal: $44.50
Restaurant tax: 6.75%
Tip: 15%
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: shouldn't `total cost` be `total_cost`?

Comment: @The6thSense find out with your 6th sense.

Comment: @The6thSense - code throws syntax errors

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am still trying to master that sense :P.

Comment: @VikramJain post the full error

Comment: @The6thSense - Fixed the bugs, Colon was missing, indent was missing, % wrongly called out. fixed it. thanks.

Comment: @martijnn2008 I rolled back your edit.  The OP said that he was experiencing syntax errors.  Edits should not change the code to be correct in that case, as the essential problem is lost.  The broken code is the problem then.  Any fixes to the code in that case should be an answer and not an edit.

Comment: @VikramJain happy that you fixed it :). Don't forget to tick the answer which answered you question :).

Answer (score 2):

Your function can just return the cost, rather than print it out within itself.

```
def cost(cost, rate, tip):
    return cost*(1+rate)*(1+tip)

print cost(44.5, 0.0675, 0.015)
```

Comment: Judging from your equation, you probably want your rate to actually be 0.0675, rather than 6.75. Otherwise 6.75 means 675%. Same goes with tip.

Comment: Thanks!!. Gotcha:)

Answer (score 0):

```
def cost(c,r,t):
    total_cost = c*(1+r)*(1+t)
    print total_cost

cost(44.5, 6.75/100, 15/100)
```

The percentage sign is a special character in Python. Replacing % sign solves the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! fixed it.